# How to execute a JavaScript function having its name as a string in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

```js
function test(arg) {
    console.log("hello! " + arg);
    return true;
}
    
window["test"]("I AM");
```

In this code snippet I execute a function by its name as a string. It works in most browsers except Microsoft Edge. How can I execute a function in Edge if I only know its name as a string? I don't want to use eval().

Comment: in `42.17134.1.0` / `17.17134`, it works.

Comment: Works for me also.

Comment: I also have 42.17134.1.0 and I get this error: Object doesn't support property or method 'test'

Comment: I execute the snippet in the console...

Comment: Seems that things defined in the console are not assigned to the global  `window` object as in other browsers, `qux = 123; alert(window.hasOwnProperty('qux'));` alerts false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define your function straight to the window object then you can call it just with the string.

`window.test=(args)=>{console.log("hello! " + arg)}`

`window["test"]("My first stack overflow answer")`

will return  "hello! My first stack overflow answer"

Comment: This is definitly a possibility for edge. I did not know about this syntax.

Comment: It's called arrow function